# TestNG is not executing all the Methods present in the Class

Tags: selenium, testng

I am automating an application using Selenium WebDriver with Java,TestNG and Maven and there is a login page present in Application under test.

Now, I am testing 2 things while automating the login functionality:

1. Login Page Title
2. Login Page Functionality

Now from above 2 methods, only first method is working(Login Page Title), and second method is not executing (Login Page Functionality), although there is no error in the TestNG while compiling and running the application.

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase {

    Login loginpage;
    HomePage homePage;

    public LoginTest() {
        super(); // method to load the System Property
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        initialization(); // method to initiate and launch the browser
        loginpage = new Login();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public HomePage LogiTest() throws IOException {
        return homePage = loginpage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void ValidateLoginPageTitleTest() {
        String title = loginpage.ValidateLoginPageTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals("Application", title);
        System.out.println(title);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Now from above two test methods, only `ValidateLoginPageTitleTest`  is executing while running the TestNG Suite.

Second method `LogiTest` is not getting picked by TestNG.

Now TestNG is showing below message on console after running the test.

```
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

PFB TestNG.xml for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="automation testing scn">

    <listeners>
        <listener
            class-name="PackageName.ExtentReportListener"></listener>
    </listeners>

    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.LoginTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods with tag @Test should be of type void to be recognized as a test by TestNG.

LogiTest() returns a HomePage item so it isn't being recognized as a runnable test by TestNG.

As an other observation, by definition, every test should have an assertion and LogiTest() is missing one. Perhaps LogiTest should be rewritten as a test or just dismissed as one.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-)

After changing the return type of the method to void, it is working fine now.

But I didn't feel that Assertion is needed in every test method, as my method is working fine also without using the Assertion.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't needed at a technical level but it's noted as a best practice. Glad your issued was resolved.